# matplotlib collection linewidth mapping?

Tags: matplotlib

I'm creating some GIS-style plots in matplotlib of road networks and the like, so I'm using LineCollection to store and represent all of the roads and color accordingly.  This is working fine, I color the roads based on a criteria and the following map:

```
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap,BoundaryNorm
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

cmap = ListedColormap(['grey','blue','green','yellow','orange','red','black'])
norm = BoundaryNorm([0,0.5,0.75,0.9,0.95,1.0,1.5,100],cmap.N)

roads = LineCollection(road_segments, array=ratios, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
axes.add_collection(roads)
```

This works fine, however I would really like to have linewidths defined in a similar manner to the color map - ranging from 0.5 to 5 for each color

Does anyone know of a clever way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

The `linewidths` keyword.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

axes = plt.axes()

roads = LineCollection([
                        [[0, 0], [1, 1]],
                        [[0, 1], [1, 0]] 
                        ], 
                       colors=['black', 'red'],
                       linewidths=[3, 8],
                       )
axes.add_collection(roads)

plt.show()
```

HTH